# A little trouble in proving that geodesic flow on Riemannian manifolds with bounded negative sectional curvature is Anosov (from Klingenberg's book)

Tags: geometry, dynamical-systems

I'm dealing with the proof from Klingenberg's "Riemannian Geometry" of the Anosov theorem on geodesic flows on complete Riemannian manifold with bounded negative sectional curvature, pages 276-278, chp.3. I hope you are familiar with the notation of Klingenberg.
In the end of p.276, it is proved that stated that for every $\tau,t\in\mathbb{R}$, given a self-adjoint operator $S_{\tau}$, for any $t\in\mathbb{R}$ the self-adjoint operators $S_{\tau}(t)$ (with $S_{\tau}(\tau)=S_{\tau}$) satisfy the Riccati-type equation
$$\frac{D}{dt}S_{\tau}(t)+S_{\tau}(t)\cdot S_{\tau}(t)+R_{\dot{c}(t)}=0.$$
Now, in the middle of p.277 it is stated that the estimate
$$|S_{\tau}(t)-S_{\tau'}(t)|\le|S_{\tau}-S_{\tau'}(\tau)|e^{-2k_{1}(t-\tau)}$$
holds for every $\displaystyle\tau'\le\tau\le t$.
So as to do this, it is proved that the remainder operator $R(t):=S_{\tau}(t)-S_{\tau'}(t)$ solves the equation
$$\frac{D}{dt}R(t)=-S_{\tau}(t)\cdot S_{\tau}(t)+S_{\tau'}(t)\cdot S_{\tau'}(t);$$
at this point, it is declared that this equation is solved as well by $R(t):=Q(t)[S_{\tau}-S_{\tau'}(\tau)]Q'(t)$ as long as $Q(\tau)=Q'(\tau)=\mathbb{I}_{n}$ and
\begin{align*}&\frac{D}{dt}Q(t)=-S_{\tau}(t)Q(t)\\&\frac{D}{dt}Q'(t)=-Q'(t)S_{\tau'}(t).\end{align*}
Here I find myself into trouble: knowing Sasaki structure on the tangent space on any point of the tangent bundle of a Riemannian manifold, I'm quite sure that covariant derivative is ok as far as $S_{\tau}(t)$ is concerned, but when it comes to $Q(t)$ and $Q'(t)$ I have the impression that the covariant derivation is not ok since they don't seem to represent tensors fields.

How to justify the latter equation for $Q(t),Q'(t)$?